# Variable use in get_template_part

Tags: page-template, get-template-part

As far as I understand (from the [get_template_part codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part#Using_loop.php_in_child_themes)) `get_template_part` is just a wrapper round the PHP require function.

So if I have a variable that I have create in a page template file e.g. `$message`, I would have assumed you could directly use that variable in the template part

So in template file:

```
<?php 
$message = 'my message';
get_template_part('messages'); 
?>
```

Then in template part messages.php:

```
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

However the echo will display nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D'oh, it just needs a `global` as its inside a function.

messages.php:

```
<?php 
global $message; 
echo $message; 
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Source](http://keithdevon.com/passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/)

You can use [`locate_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) to find the template file to include. Bit cleaner than using globals.

Ie `require(locate_template('messages'));`

Answer (score 0):

If you use locate_template() instead of get_template_part() you can use all variables in that script:

```
<?php include(locate_template('message.php')); ?>
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

Echo $message will work.

Comment: This seems to be the same as [@Sam's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124855/5433)